# crystal reports columns in different pages

Tags: crystal-reports

This is special requirement in which if there are 10 columns, let it be column1 to column10 of the same table.

Then in the first page of report---contain Column1 to column5
and in second page of report--contain column6 to column10.

Please help in this regard.

Report page no1
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5

Report page no2
Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10

NB:-Here column1 to column10 belong to same table.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your columns 1 to 5 are in detail section. Add one more detail section, in that section add sub report. In that subreport add your remaining columns. In section expert of 1st detail section check Page break after and also check underlay following section. I think this will help.